# Could not set the RowSource Property. Invalid Property Value

Tags: vba, excel, listboxitem

I have an excel where I have populated few data in column 'A', I want the data to appear in the List box which is in my User Form. But I'm repeatedly getting the Run-time Error 380 stating "Could not set the RowSource Property. Invalid property value" 
Below is the code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim wb123 As Workbook, TempFile As Workbook
Dim Tempsheet As Worksheet
Dim Last_Row As Integer


 Set wb123 = ThisWorkbook
Set TempFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\inkapb\AppData\Local\Temp\EPC AutoTool\Projects\" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "\Template.xlsm")

 Set Tempsheet = TempFile.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Last_Row = Tempsheet.Cells(Tempsheet.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     With ListBox1

    .ColumnCount = 1
    .ColumnWidths = "50"
    .RowSource = Tempsheet.Range("A2:A" & Last_Row).Address
End With


End Sub
```

And here is my excel sheet which contains the data.

[image]

Comment: Tempsheet.Range("A2:A" & Last_Row).Address should be "tempsheet!A2:A" & last_row

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - I changed it but still the same error

Comment: @Gareth - The error is occurring in --> .RowSource = Tempsheet.Range("A2:A" & Last_Row).Address

Comment: have you done .RowSource="tempsheet!A2:A" & last_row ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav that's not the issue as `Tempsheet` is assigned a worksheet earlier

Comment: @KarthikPB What's the value of `Last_Row` when the error occurs?

Comment: @Nathan_Savn - Yes Exactly, .RowSource = "Tempsheet!A2:A" & Last_Row

Comment: @Gareth - Last_Row has the value 23

Comment: Sorry, tempsheet.name & "!A2:A" & last_row" ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - Hard luck buddy! Still the same error

Comment: Have you tried the list property like ListBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - YES!!! this is worked like a charm. Thanks a ton!

Comment: What is the result of `Tempsheet.Range("A2:A" & Last_Row).Address`. checked with `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` etc.

Comment: No probs, but there is an issue with the other way that you should try to get to the bottom of.  Good luck.

Comment: @PankajR - it contains all the data's which I have I have posted in the screen shot.

Comment: @KarthikPB may be I was not clear. Let me put it this way: What you get in a Msg box if you execute `MsgBox Tempsheet.Range("A2:A" & Last_Row).Address` at that point.

Comment: @PankajR I got $A$2:$A$32 - this is because I have data from A2 till A32 in the Column 'A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works for me, when you are in the Userform Module, step through the code by pressing F8, this will step through each line of the code. See if these variables are collecting values.

### [image: Variables]

If there are no values when you step through the lines, then something could be wrong with the "TempFile", such as the wrong sheet or something.

Also make sure your Rowsource is blank in the Listbox properties.

### [image]

You can also use the List Properties instead of rowsource, for example:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim wb123 As Workbook, TempFile As Workbook
    Dim Tempsheet As Worksheet
    Dim Last_Row As Long, rng As Range


    Set wb123 = ThisWorkbook
    Set TempFile = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Dave\Downloads\" & ComboBox1)

    Set Tempsheet = TempFile.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With Tempsheet
        Last_Row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & Last_Row)
    End With


    With ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 1
        .ColumnWidths = "50"
        .List = rng.Value
    End With

    TempFile.Close True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll definitely try this approach.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix you could substitute

`.RowSource = Tempsheet.Range("A2:A" & Last_Row).Address`

with

`.RowSource = "=Sheet2!A2:A" & Last_Row`

Another way to do it is to use a `For` loop to got through the cells and add them one at a time. I usually use the way below if I want to do some additional actions before adding an item to my combo box e.g. have an `If` statement to judge if I want that cell value to be added.

```
For i = 2 to Last_Row 'Start from row 2 to Last_Row
     .AddItem Tempsheet.Cells(i,1).Value 'Add the item in the first column
Next i
```

Comment: Yes it's working fine with this particular for loop approach too. Thanks a ton! Now I have couple of more ways to achieve the end result :)